# Replatforming Swing Application to web application?

Tags: java, php

I have a fairly large Java application in production (30k lines of code). It uses a decent sized library of business objects I wrote in Java and I have a Swing interface thrown on top of it.

However,it functions as a standalone desktop application currently with no server-side at all (except for a MySQL database and some text files housing central data). As data volume and calculation needs increase, this is becoming a problem running on just a quad core workstation with five threads and 4GB of RAM.

I'm thinking of going the modern route and create a web based application using PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc. However, I don't want to rewrite my Java business object libraries from scratch in PHP (and I dont like the loose type style of PHP). I'd prefer to keep everything in Java so I can use my current business object library. That way I only have to scrap the Swing interface and serve up dynamic web pages instead, and have a Java server use the current business object libraries to calculate everything.

I've done research but I dont know what I'm looking for as there seems to be several disparate options. Does Apache have a Java web server solution or something that accomplishes this? What is the best way to transform a Java application into a web application?

Comment: You could use JSP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript in a servlet container, would mean not having to do away with the Java business layer.  You could use J2EE as a management container as well.

Comment: *Does Apache have a Java web server solution?* Yes. *something that accomplishes this?* Not directly. You might find [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/overview.html) a good match. There are a lot of choices.

Comment: So is JSP a strong substitute for PHP? I kept getting the impression if I wanted to do pure web development I would have to do PHP. But I find PHP a little too loose and informal for my liking.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the UI layer with [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/swing). Vaadin UI code is almost like Swing code and is executed in the JVM (typically in Java EE server or in plain servlet container with e.g. Spring). That is why you can most likely recycle the most essential parts of your application.